# How to push array in post method Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, http, post

I have created a post method and I need to push students id in body parameter. My api expect this formatted data:

```
[date] => 2021-09-24
[time] => 11:27 AM
[no_of_attendance] => 1
[ids] => Array
    (
         [19243] => 19243
         [19250] => 19250
         [19259] => 19259
         [19260] => 19260
         [19316] => 19316
      )

[save_as] => draft
```

When I am sending data my log is showing this values:

```
Data: {date: 2021-09-26, time: 03:18 PM, no_of_attendance: 1, ids: [18047, 18093, 18289, 18047, 18093], save_as: draft}
```

I am collecting student's id via SwitchListTile where I am adding student id in my List variable.

How can I post data to my api?

My Post method:

```
static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> sendDraftOrFinalData(
      departmentId, batchId, semester, courseId, token, Map data) async {
    final url =
        Api.baseUrl + 'attendance_students/$departmentId/$batchId/$semester/$courseId?token=$token';

    print('Data: $data');

    final response = await client.post(Uri.parse(url), body: data);

    final responseBody = json.decode(response.body);

    return responseBody;
  }
```

My controller where I am calling my post method:

```
void saveAsDraftOrFinal(departmentId, batchId, semester, courseId, saveAs) async {
    try {
      if (dateSelectError.value) {
        isLoading.value = true;
        await RemoteServices.sendDraftOrFinalData(
            departmentId, batchId, semester, courseId, token, {
          'date': selectedDate.value,
          'time': selectedTime.value,
          'no_of_attendance': selectedAttendanceTime.value.toString(),
          'ids': selectedStudentsIds.toString(), // This is my student ids list
          'save_as': saveAs,
        }).then((value) {
          print('Attendance Response: $value');
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }
```

When I am submitting data, I am getting this error:

```
E/flutter (21836): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (21836): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (21836): ^
E/flutter (21836): 
E/flutter (21836): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
E/flutter (21836): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1272:9)
E/flutter (21836): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:937:22)
E/flutter (21836): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter (21836): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
E/flutter (21836): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
E/flutter (21836): #6      RemoteServices.sendDraftOrFinalData (package:diu_qr_code_scanner/services/remote_services.dart:94:31)
E/flutter (21836): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21836): #7      AttendanceController.saveAsDraftOrFinal (package:diu_qr_code_scanner/controllers/attendance_controller.dart:65:9)
E/flutter (21836): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: what you see if you add `print(response);` before calling `final responseBody = json.decode(response.body);`?

Comment: Attendance Response: Instance of 'Response'

Comment: ok i thought that `Response.toString` method is more verbose... try `print(response.statusCode)` and `print(response.body)`

Comment: I/flutter (21836): Attendance Response: Instance of 'Response'
I/flutter (21836): Attendance Status Code: 500
I/flutter (21836): Attendance Body: <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (21836): <html>
I/flutter (21836):     <head>
I/flutter (21836):         <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
I/flutter (21836):         <style>
I/flutter (21836):             /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */

Comment: you have status code `500` more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500

Comment: If I send single string as ids value than my response get successfull message. In api they are looping student id with forEach and pushing the array as array index. But I can't find any option to push array index in dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by updating my controller method:

```
void saveAsDraftOrFinal(departmentId, batchId, semester, courseId, saveAs) async {
    try {
      if (dateSelectError.value) {
        isLoading.value = true;
        await RemoteServices.sendDraftOrFinalData(
            departmentId, batchId, semester, courseId, token, {
          'date': selectedDate.value,
          'time': selectedTime.value,
          'no_of_attendance': selectedAttendanceTime.value.toString(),
          for (var id in selectedStudentsIds)
            'ids[${id.toString()}]': id.toString(),
          'save_as': saveAs,
        }).then((value) {
          print('Attendance Response: $value');
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }
```

Then my post data is like below:

```
Data: {date: 2021-09-26, time: 05:56 PM, no_of_attendance: 1, save_as: final, ids[19243]: 19243, ids[19250]: 19250}
```